# Python While loop not iterating variable only print commands

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, while-loop, clock

Background context - I'm making a peculiar clock that will display the time via WS2812B pixels and learning as I go!

I have a dictionary that will contain the commands being sent to the pixels as below

```
hourvalues = {1: "Hour One",
              2: "Hour Two"}
```

etc etc up to 24
And the main document contains the loop:

```
while True:
    print(hourvalues[hour])
    sleep(1)
```

This works wonderfully for now with print (as a test) and I get a word every second. However, if I change the dictionary to

```
hourvalues = {1: print("Hour One"),
              2: Print("Hour Two")}
```

and the body to

```
while True:
    hourvalues[hour]
    sleep(1)
```

in order to represent the final thing where it will be sending a command, not printing a line, I get just a single word, and that's it.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my first post, be gentle! Thanks all

Comment: `print()` is called twice on initialization of `hourvalues` dict and as a result you got `{1: None, 2: None}`. It happens, cause `print()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you call the `print` function when you build the dictionary, it will print out the value at that time, and then store the return value (`None`) in the actual dictionary.

Instead, you want to create a dictionary of functions that will print the given string when called.  The `lambda` expression is useful for cases like this where you want to build a small function to use in one spot:

```
hour_actions = {
    1: lambda: print("Hour One"),
    2: lambda: print("Hour Two")
}

while True:
    hour_actions[hour]()
    sleep(1)
```

Note that you need to use `()` to actually call the function that you get from the dictionary!

Comment: About to go do some reading up ton lambda. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the function as dict value, not its return value, as you are doing in your second piece of code.

So, it could look like:

```
def hour_one():
    print('Hour one')

def hour_two():
    print('Hour two')

hourvalues = {1: hour_one,  # no (), you don't want to call it
              2: hour_two}  # while creating the dict !

for hour in [1, 2]:
    hourvalues[hour]()  # call it now
```